# Where's the conventional place to store git repositories in a linux file system tree?

Tags: linux, git

If I make an analogy with the hosting of a web server, I would say that git's data should be in `/var/git`, so my git repository would be in `/var/git/myrepo`

**Q**: Is that the right guess ?

Comment: The _correct_ answer is `/srv/git`, and official git's manual uses this path as well: [link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There is no right or wrong answer here, except the one dictated by your own personal religion and the contents of the `hier(7)` manpage on your system.

[typical Linux `hier` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/7/hier) ; [typical BSD `hier` manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=hier&sektion=7))

`/var/git/*` seems reasonable to me personally. That's where I keep mine.

Comment: Similarly, in Arch Linux apache's folder is /srv/http (instead of /var/www like some other distros) so I put my git stuff in /srv/git.

Comment: Somewhere under /var/ seems reasonable, but see also Denis R's answer below: https://serverfault.com/a/433584/45819 - he puts it into /var/lib/git with good reasons

Comment: Wrong answer! The correct answer would have been something along the lines of "anywhere under /home/{user}"

Comment: @anton1980: and _who_ would be "correct" user in this case? Remember this is a git _server_

Answer (score 37):

Place it in a directory (or shared filesystem) under `/srv`. This is what it's for.

The `/srv` directory is intended for [site-specific data served by the system](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM). From the standard:

> This main purpose of specifying this is so that users may find the
>   location of the data files for particular service, and so that
>   services which require a single tree for readonly data, writable data
>   and scripts (such as cgi scripts) can be reasonably placed. Data that
>   is only of interest to a specific user should go in that users' home
>   directory.
>
> The methodology used to name subdirectories of `/srv` is unspecified as
>   there is currently no consensus on how this should be done. One method
>   for structuring data under `/srv` is by protocol, eg. `ftp`, `rsync`, `www`,
>   and `cvs`. On large systems it can be useful to structure `/srv` by
>   administrative context, such as `/srv/physics/www`, `/srv/compsci/cvs`,
>   etc. This setup will differ from host to host. Therefore, no program
>   should rely on a specific subdirectory structure of `/srv` existing or
>   data necessarily being stored in `/srv`. However `/srv` should always
>   exist on FHS compliant systems and should be used as the default
>   location for such data.
>
> Distributions must take care not to remove locally placed files in
>   these directories without administrator permission.

---

On an SELinux-enabled system, the default directory is `/var/www/git`, and repos should be in subdirectories thereof. Or, you can use, e.g. `/srv/git` and set the file context to be equivalent:

```
semanage fcontext -a -e /var/www/git /srv/git
```

Comment: Another wrong answer. The author said "my git repository". This is clearly his data, not relevant to any other users of the system. So, it should go somewhere under ~/

Comment: @anton1980 You seem to have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @anton1980 He clearly speaks about an analogy of "hosting a web server" so we are talking about git repos he is serving to the outside world. Why you think this "is clearly his data, not relevant to others", would be interesting. Also, please don't post the same comment under every answer ;)

Comment: "data files for particular service" --> this makes it clear, and the Git's official manual ([link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server)) uses this path as well. However, it's also worth mentioning that although using /var for this purpose is not right, it's a very common "wrong" and so probably safe. I'd personally stick to the /srv though, its name makes more sense to me. Also I don't agree with /var/lib/git as to me, it is a place that the git as a service itself might want to use.

Answer (score 7):

```
/home/git/
```

This might seem a bit unconventional at first but it is very reasonable as this directory is made for you (with correct permissions) when you do `sudo useradd git`. You can just switch to the git user, `cd` and immediately run:

```
$ mkdir .ssh; chmod 700 .ssh
$ touch .ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

and put public keys of your peers into the just created authorized_keys file.

After you `git init --bare` your project, the "url" is then just...wait for it...

```
git@<server>:<project>
```

Comment: Almost like recommended in "Pro Git" book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: Yes!! It should go under "home". More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/897782/the-place-to-store-user-data-in-linux

Comment: You still have a nice `git@<server>:<project>` URL _regardless_ of **where** `git` user's home directory is. It doesn't have to be under `/home`, and, being a service account, I don't recommend that path. `useradd -d /var/lib/git git` yield the same result.

Answer (score 2):

As voretaq7 said, there is no right or wrong answer on such a subject.
However, if you want to follow of softs, it seems that database softs store their data in

```
/var/lib/soft
```

For example, for Postgresql 9.1 on debian the folder is

```
/var/lib/postgresql/9.1/
```

So I would personnaly choose

```
/var/lib/git
```

Answer (score 2):

On my Arch Linux I have `/srv/http` for apache (which is system default) and I use it for my node.js http servers too. Similarly I decided to just put all git repositories in `/srv/git`.

I use GitLab, and `/srv/git` is the home folder for git in that case too.

Ultimately, it's up to you. I found that sticking to a format similar to other services in your distro is easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely up to you. Optimally, though, you should put the git data dir on a separate partition or even disk to make system upgrades etc. easier and of course, you have to make sure that there is enough disk space available.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can choose whereever you have permission but **Git Project** offers

```
/home/user/my_project
```

at [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository).

Answer (score 0):

If you use some frontend to git, just go with wherever the one packaged by your distribution wants to place them. Anything else is just creating needless incompatibilities.

Comment: 1/ I'm not using a frontend to git
2/ Git doens't come with a recomendation on where to place git repositories... any folder where you do git init is a git repository.

Comment: 1/ By front end i would assume the git server  serving the repos. 2/ any such server, even if only a HTTP server is used would have a default location.  Of course we are talking about the location for hosting, when you work with the code the .git is mostly inside the project.

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding the suggestion to use /srv, you are under the assumption that all git repositories are used for websites. It may be true for you, but you could have a piece of software that is not a website.

Second, by storing your code repositories outside of the /var/www/html or /srv/html, you get two nice benefits. You can create symbolic links into your repo at any level, making it easier to hide your libraries. Also, if your repository's location changes at all, you don't have to modify your virtual host configurations. Instead you just adjust your symbolic links.

I was using /var/repo, but I think /var/git is better, and will be using that from now on.

Answer (score 0):

When I am downloading git repos in order to maintain site configurations which I then deploy I store them in

/data/repos/$REPO_GROUP_OR_USER/$REPO_NAME

Answer (score 0):

To add another option to the pool: as the linux kernel headers and DKMS kernel module sources are installed into `/usr/src/` on debian, I've mounted a BTRFS volume under `/usr/src/repos/` where all the git projects go...
Now I just need to transfer that volume off the end of the slowest hard disk in my machine xD